# I need to do an excel but I do not want the user to download it automatically, but first it is saved in a server path, how can I do that?

Tags: php, excel, server

I need to do an excel but I do not want the user to download it automatically, but first it is saved in a server path, how can I do that?

I have this code, but it downloads automatically and that's what I do not want it to do

```
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("content-disposition: attachment;filename=Reporte.xls");
```

Comment: i assume there is some code somewhere that creates the 'excel' ?

Comment: You don't show any writing of the Excel file to the response stream, but instead of doing that you would write it to disk.  You need to provide a little more detail if you want answers which are more useful...